# How do you set the method "isChecked()" state to default to true in a ListView?

Tags: android

I need the checkboxes in my listview checked by default so that it returns true for the value of `isChecked()`.

I am using the Simple Multiple choice list item layout provided by the sdk supplied in `android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice`

I have set the ListView adapter like this:

---

> adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice, list);
>
> setListAdapter(adapter);

---

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have used the following code for Setting the Check boxes Default Checked in my application

```
adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice, list);
setListAdapter(adapter);
l1 = getListView();
for (i = 0; i < getListAdapter().getCount(); i++) {
l1.setItemChecked(i, true);
}
```

and the output, listview came with multiple check boxes default checked